# Work done on gas by piston

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, work, ideal-gas

In this problem there is a cylinder that is closed at both ends and has thermally insulated walls.  It is divided into 2 parts by a movable, frictionless, thermally insulated piston.  There is a heating coil in the left side of the cylinder and there are $N$ molecules of an ideal gas in each compartment.  The original temperature and volume on each side are To and $V_o$.  The left side is slowly warmed with the coil until its pressure doubles.

How much work was done on the gas on the right?
I calculated the final temperature and volume of each side after the left side is heated but I'm unsure about the work calculation.  Would the work simply be $W = -P(V_f - V_o)$ where $P$ is 2 times the original pressure (so its $2NkT_o/V_o$) or do I have to do something with the pressure since it changes from $P$ to $2P$?

Comment: I calculated the work done by you in reference to this question, and it appears to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is only $-P(V_f-V_o)$ (considering the final $P = 2$ times the original as you did)

Comment: So the work done only depends on the final pressure of the gas? Also to find the work done on the right, do I use the volume of the left side?

Comment: It depends on the final pressure and the volume change (Vf-Vo). The volume of the left side is already considered when you use Vf-Vo (the left side volume change is the oposite of the right side one (=Vo-Vf)

Comment: Note that in this case "[the work] depends on the final pressure and the volume change ($V_f-V_o$)" is true only because the left side is heated "slowly", that is, we're dealing with an adiabatic process. In general, the work (and the heat as well), is a path function, not state function.

Comment: @SimeonCarstens  You are right of course. In this case as it is an ideal gas and everything is said to be thermally insulated to keep the adiabatic conditions, the case is for simple calculation and not a real situation without simplifications.